# fetch_row alternative in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How do I get this in Codeigniter? If I tried in a same, it show Fatal error: non object 'fetch_row', please help me to get using alternative in codeigniter for `fetch_row`.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT attnDate 
        FROM tbl_attendance
        ORDER BY attnDate";
$res = $g_link->query($sql);   // mysqli query

while ($row = $res->fetch_row()) {
    $dates[] = $row[0];
}
```

get $dates As below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-11-25
    [1] => 2015-11-29
    [2] => 2015-11-30
    [3] => 2015-12-01
    [4] => 2015-12-02
    [5] => 2015-12-03
    [6] => 2015-12-05
    [7] => 2015-12-06
    [8] => 2015-12-07
    [9] => 2015-12-08
    [10] => 2015-12-09
    [11] => 2015-12-10
    [12] => 2015-12-12
)
```

As I trying in codeigniter:
Model:

```
public function raw_attendance_Status(){
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('attnDate');
        $this->db->from('tbl_attendance');
        $this->db->order_by('attnDate');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function rawAttendance(){
        $data['date1'] = $this->AttendanceModel->raw_attendance_Status();
        $this->load->view('attendance/rawAttendance', $data);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess using `result_array()` can do it for you!

```
 $this->db->distinct();
 $this->db->select('attnDate');
 $this->db->from('tbl_attendance');
 $this->db->order_by('attnDate');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, result_array() direct return this output or need fetch with foreach?

Comment: you do not need to fetch anything out of it as you stated in the question! just do a `var_dump()` on the result and you will know what you have got!